# Using C outb function in C# with System.IO

Tags: c#, io

I have an old software development source code to transfer data from PC to and specific hardware.

This code use the method [outb](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/inb.2.html)(value,port) to write value in the specific port. I can't use the binary files in modern operative system so, I thought make a new version with C#, porting this C code to C# code.

I'm not familiar with System.IO.Ports namespace. Someone knows how I can use a method similar to outb() in C#?¿

Thanks

Comment: `System.IO.Ports` is for serial ports ... on linux you are using serial like files using `open("/dev/xxx", ...)`  when `outb` can be used for not only serial ports ... if your app was using `outb` to send somthing to serial then `System.IO.Ports` you may try to use it

Comment: interesting ... [`FileStream.Seek` on linux is using lseek](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/FileStream.Unix.cs#L812) ... if we add this with [An alternate method to outb](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/IO-Port-Programming-2.html) seems like you can use `FileStream` with `/dev/port` then set Position = port  (as FileStream.Position use Seek and Seek use native lseek) and write should act as `outb` ... it just a theory based on quick googling (very platform specific)